# make width of <td> responsive to the outer <div>'s width

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside of `div` and I am trying to set the width so that the columns on the output **fill the whole div with id left**.

Here is all the code and along with jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qsogubjd/

```css
#sortPanel {
    width: 565px;
    height: 165px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
}

#sortPanel td {
    height: 165px;
    width: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.cc {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.ccH1 {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #F22613;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.ccH2 {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #F2B705;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}


#left {
    width: 590px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <table id="sortPanel">
    <tr>
      <td id="b0">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 144px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b1">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 35px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b2">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 6px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b3">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 64px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b4">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 12px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b5">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 153px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b6">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 70px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b7">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 137px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b8">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 19px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b9">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 131px;"></div>
      </td>
     
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So far I tried putting `position: relative;` on selectors, it didn't work. Then I tried `display: block;`, it didn't work either.

To make reading code easier:

The `width` attribute of `td` defines the seperation between the columns in the html output. Increasing the value of `width` will set columns further for each other, spreading them.

While `width` of `div` inside of `td` sets the width of column itself. Increasing this value will make colums thicker.

As far as I researched the solution should include **%**: `width: someValue%`.

How can I change the css code in order to spead the columns across the div with id "left" and make the whole table responsive?

Comment: Why are you using table layout here? Is this table will always have one row? Also, why do you make `display: block` from table cells? I suppose using tables here looks wrong.

Comment: You've overcomplicated it by adding the `display` styles. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

The following caused the issue:

1. table#sortPanel has a display: block;
2. td.cc has a display: block;
3. table has a defined width (565px)
4. td has a defined width (5px)

td's naturally expand to occupy full width of the table without the need of any css.
When td's are given display: block, they loose this natural property.

Just remove these styles and td's will occupy full span of the table.
Give table a width: 100% and it'll occupy the full span of div#left.

Here is your code with modifications:

```
    <div id="left">
    <table id="sortPanel">
        <tr>
            <td id="b0">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 144px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b1">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 35px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b2">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 6px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b3">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 64px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b4">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 12px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b5">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 153px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b6">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 70px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b7">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 137px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b8">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 19px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="b9">
                <div class="cc" style="height: 131px;"></div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    #sortPanel {
    //width: 565px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 165px;
    margin: 10px 0x;
    //display: block;
    display: table;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
}

#sortPanel td {
    height: 165px;
    //width: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    //display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.cc {
    display: block;
    //width: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    //position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.ccH1 {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #F22613;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.ccH2 {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #F2B705;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#left {
    width: 590px;
    //height: 190px;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #333);
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpr4ztvj/

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete some of the unnecessary attribute value pairs specifically related to `display` and `position`, those are very important in css, be sure to read up on them. I added the changes in the comments of css code and also I will share fiddle link to check the responsiveness https://jsfiddle.net/nukjh6ea/, now you may add up td s as you want.

```css
#sortPanelA, sortPanelB {
  width: 100%;/* occupy the whole width of div left */
  height: 165px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
}

#sortPanelA td, sortPanelB td {
  height: 165px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.cc {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;/* the width of column, you may play around with it */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #999;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ccH1 {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #F22613;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.ccH2 {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #F2B705;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#left {
  width: 90%;/* take up the 90% of body */
  height: 190px;
  margin: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #333);
  background: linear-gradient(#444, #333);
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <table id="sortPanelA">
    <tr>
      <td id="b0">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 144px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b1">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 35px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b2">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 6px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b3">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 64px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b4">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 12px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b5">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 153px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b6">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 70px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b7">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 137px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="b8">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 19px;"></div>
      </td>
      
      <td id="b9">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 131px;"></div>
      </td>
      
    
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.cc {width: 100%}` and `#sortPanelA td {width: 3.5rem}`

**EDIT**

To make whole table responsive here are steps:

- change div, table and tbody width to 100%
- set table `display: table`
- remove td width
- set div.cc to 100%
- set , not with css

Here is the code in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/meshin/uuL2f43g/

Comment: why 3.5rem, would it possible to have solution with %, your code just works only for this case. When the number of columns increase it breaks

Comment: I've added another answer to make whole table responsive and fill it 100% with columns based on percentage of each. Hope that is what you're looking for

Comment: the same problem, try adding one more `td` for example `<td id="b10" width="10%">
        <div class="cc" style="height: 131px;"></div>
      </td>` and it breaks

Comment: If you want to have more TD elements then % of width set on them has to be devide by number of them. For example 10 TD elements and width is 100/10=10%, but if 20 TD elemets then 100/20=5%. So for 20 TD elemets it's `width="5%"`

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing and matching different block models without understanding what they do. A table block model is pretty responsive by default and by adding blocks and inline-blocks to things you're complicating matters.

Remove all the `display: block` and `display: inline-block` from your table elements. Then set the `.cc` div to 100% width of the table cell. Your table will then scale to whatever you need. If you want it 100% set the table to 100%.

**See example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mede6n8j/**

**Steps to fix:**

- Remove `display: block;` from `#sortPanelA, sortPanelB`
- Remove `display: block` and `display:inline-block;` from `#sortPanelA td, sortPanelB td`
- Remove `width: 11px;` from `#sortPanelA td, sortPanelB td`
- Change `width: 5px;` to `width: 100%` on `.cc`. This will make the divs scale to the table-cells

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to first try making the table width 100% , It should work.

In case if it does not work then since you have 9 td's in a row try setting the td with to 11.11%. But if you have n number of td then it will not work.

Regards,
Vinit Patil.